# How to store strings with spaces as a cookie in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I am trying to make a cookie but the team name I am getting from my database contains a space and it gives me this error : 
 '**The cookie name "Czech Republic" contains invalid characters.**'

and this is what I see in my url : `http://localhost:8000/myteam/Czech%20Republic`

**The code from my view where I acces the route :**

```
 @foreach($teams as $teamitem)
    <a href="{{URL::route('storeTeamCookie', $teamitem->name)}}">
    </a>
 @endforeach
```

**The code in my controller:**

```
public function storeCookie($team) 
{
  $cookie = Cookie::make($team, $team, 3600);
}
```

**The code in my routes.php file :**

```
Route::get('/myteam/{team}', array('as' => 'storeTeamCookie', 'uses' => 'MyteamController@storeCookie'));
```

Comment: well, like it says - cookies names can't have spaces. use a different name, e.g. `teamName=Czech Republic`. there's no "no-spaces" restriction on cookie VALUES.

Comment: Thanks for you're response, are there other ways to do this with laravel ? because I would have do add a field in my databank just for this then (because I am using the name for other causes too) and that doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: I fixed it with str_replace , answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

User `urlencode` and `urldecode` on the name when setting and getting the cookie/

```
$cookie = Cookie::make(urldecode($team), $team, 3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the str_replace() method

code in controller :

```
public function storeCookie($team) 
{
    $team = str_replace(' ', '', $team);
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::make($team, $team, 3600));

    return View::make('myteam')->with('teams', $teams);
}
```